# MagentoService is not available after adding service reference

Tags: c#, soap, magento-1.9

I am using [this example](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024900/C+Magento+1.x+SOAP+v2+API) to get the SOAP interface working on my Magento 1.9 shop. And it all seemed to work okay, I can add the service reference, and I get a `MagentoSOAP.com.example.myshop` namespace added. (`MagentoSOAP` is the namespace of my project).

But, according to the example given, I should have a `MagentoService` available in that namespace, but it is not there. I can see all the classes in the `MagentoSOAP.com.example.myshop` namespace, but no service.

I know the SOAP API works, because in PHP I get response from it.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

The class you want is not `MagentoService` but `PortTypeClient`:

```
using MyNamespace.com.example.shop;

...

PortTypeClient client = new PortTypeClient();
string sessionId = client.login("user", "api key");

// example call
var result = client.catalogInventoryStockItemList(sessionId, new string[] { "SKU" });
```